# Place 28 dominoes in a loop

Tags: combinatorics, dominoes

A standard set of double-six [dominoes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominoes) has 28 tiles with 2 numbers on each side from 0 to 6. Tiles can be placed next to each other if the numbers at each end match. Can you place all the 28 tiles such that they form a loop? Note that the end number must also match the front number to complete the loop.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Note that

> the numbers, $0-6$, are elements of the finite field $\mathbb{F}_7$.

So there are

> circles like this: $(0)(d)|(d)(2d)|\cdots|(6d)(0)$ for every $d\in\mathbb{F}_7^\times$.

Now just

> connect all the circles, and insert the remaining $7$ tiles of the form $(d)(d)$ anywhere you like.

The final answer:

> 00 01 11 12 22 23 33 34 44 45 55 56 66 60 02 24 46 61 13 35 50 03 36 62 25 51 14 40

Comment: That is correct! Great answer.

Comment: You don't need the finite field, as any set of cycles will do. It is essentially an Eulerian circuit through a complete graph (with a loop on each vertex), and the method you describe is a general algorithm for any graph that admits a Eulerian circuit.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis Of course I understand the interpretation of eulerian circuit on the complete graph, but the question is exactly to describe such a circuit, right? And I found it most convenient to interpret it as finite field elements... So I don't quite get your point.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis Well... upon carefully reading the question, it does say "Can you place ...". So perhaps you mean a better answer should be "yes I can, because $7$ is an odd number"?

Comment: I just meant that you can just start laying out a line of dominoes until you can't extend it any further. At that point it will be a circle (yes, because 7 is odd). It just seemed to be so oddly specific to construct the circles the way you did, making it seem as if there was a reason for it, as if only those circles will do.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis From my point of view, I produced all needed circles by writing down only one, which is a quite compact way of expressing. A solution is a solution, there is nothing "oddly specific" about it, and nobody says "only those circles will do".